# Why would this function wont receive my inputbox.value as parameters?

Tags: javascript

I am just a beginner: I tried other examples without DOM Manipulation and it works. Please help. thanks.

```
let para1 = document.getElementById("para1");
let para2 = document.getElementById("para2");
let btnFunctionPara = document.getElementById("btnFunctionPara");

let para1Output = document.getElementById("para1Output");
let para2Output = document.getElementById("para2Output");

btnFunctionPara.addEventListener(
  "click",
  displayParaOutput(para1.value, para2.value)
);
```

when I try to log the para1value or para2value
This is what it says:

```js
let para1 = document.getElementById("para1");
let para2 = document.getElementById("para2");
let btnFunctionPara = document.getElementById("btnFunctionPara");

let para1Output = document.getElementById("para1Output");
let para2Output = document.getElementById("para2Output");

btnFunctionPara.addEventListener(
  "click",
  displayParaOutput(para1.value, para2.value)
);

function displayParaOutput(para1value, para2value) {
  para1Output.innerHTML = para1value;
  para2Output.innerHTML = para2value;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, #28b487, #7dd56f);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

p {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #000;
  /* text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #000; */
  font-weight: bold;
}

.l_container {
  padding: 180px 0;
  margin: 100px 0;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.box_type01 {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 20px 15px;
  border: 1px solid orangered;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.u_mab10 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.u_mab20 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.u_mab30 {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.u_mab40 {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.u_mab50 {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.u_mat10 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.u_mat20 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.u_mat30 {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.u_mat40 {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.u_mat50 {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.ALcenter {
  text-align: center;
}
.ttl_type01 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.l_wrap {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.u_flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
  <h1 class="u_mab10">Challenge #76</h1>
    <p>FUNCTION WITH PARAMETERS</p>
    <br /><br />
    <div class="box_type01">
      <div class="u_flex">
        <input type="text" id="para1" />
        <input type="text" id="para2" />
        <button id="btnFunctionPara">Enter</button>
      </div>
      <br />
      <p id="para1Output"></p>
      <p id="para2Output"></p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <hr />

    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

Uncaught ReferenceError: para1value is not defined
at :1:1

```
function displayParaOutput(para1value, para2value) {
  para1Output.innerHTML = para1value;
  para2Output.innerHTML = para2value;
}
```

I am just a beginner: I tried other examples without DOM Manipulation and it works. Please help. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event listener is calling a function instead of a passing a function. Wrap it in `function(){...}`.

```js
let para1 = document.getElementById("para1");
let para2 = document.getElementById("para2");
let btnFunctionPara = document.getElementById("btnFunctionPara");

let para1Output = document.getElementById("para1Output");
let para2Output = document.getElementById("para2Output");

btnFunctionPara.addEventListener(
  "click",
  function() {displayParaOutput(para1.value, para2.value);}
);

function displayParaOutput(para1value, para2value) {
  para1Output.innerHTML = para1value;
  para2Output.innerHTML = para2value;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="u_mab10">Challenge #76</h1>
    <p>FUNCTION WITH PARAMETERS</p>
    <br /><br />
    <div class="box_type01">
      <div class="u_flex">
        <input type="text" id="para1" />
        <input type="text" id="para2" />
        <button id="btnFunctionPara">Enter</button>
      </div>
      <br />
      <p id="para1Output"></p>
      <p id="para2Output"></p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <hr />
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You solved my problem, I thought that I just need to call the function to pass the values on my parameters. Thank you so much!